# Is there any verb for "keeping someone from seeing something"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

His realistic view keeps him from seeing the significance of human right considerations.

Is there any verb to be used instead of "keeps him from seeing" in the above sentence?

Comment: _blind_ (verb) 2. deprive (someone) of understanding, judgement, or perception [ODO] _"he was blinded by his faith"_

Comment: 'blinds him to'?

Comment: You could look in a thesaurus for synonyms of *conceal* and *obscure* and see if anything there suits. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/conceal will get you started.

Comment: 'To pull the wool over someone's eyes' -- not so much a verb, more of an idiom that means to do something to prevent somebody from knowing about something.

Answer (score 2):

***Blinkering*** can stand for “keeping someone from seeing something”.

ODO:

> **[blinker](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blinker)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **1.1** Cause (someone) to have a narrow or limited outlook on a situation:
>   ‘university education blinkers researchers so that they
>   see poverty in terms of their own specialization’
>
> ‘A quarter-century of industrial thinking originating from Europe and
>   North America continues to blinker us from this reality.’

Answer (score 1):

> His realism-based views **blinded him to** the importance of respecting of human rights.

Alternately:

> He was **blinded by** his realism-based views, and could not understand the importance of respecting  human rights.
>
> He was **blind to** the importance of respecting human rights.
>
> He was **blinded by** his realism-based views.

In usage, to be "blinded to" and / or "blinded by" can each specify the cause and the object of selective understanding or perception, or they can focus only on the cause or only on the object.

A highly related proverb is "There are none so blind as those who will not see."  Unlike "blinded by" and more like "blind to" it can indicate innate, intentional, or willful ignorance, as might be implied by "He was blind to human rights."

Comment: I like your idea.  I suggest you replace *realistic* with *pragmatic*.

Comment: @aparente001 -- I agree! I have "realistic" because it is the original language example given by the OP -- but I think "pragmatic" works better. If you suggest OP update the question, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Personally I think you should go ahead and change your answer.  I think this would strengthen your answer.  (It looks a little weird right now!)  Optionally, you could explain why.

Comment: Just like to mention that the "realistic" in the original question is supposed to refer to realism in international relations, a view to the effect that countries' foreign policies should be guided only by national interests.

Comment: Interesting. Using "realistic" in describing someone is usually an assessment -- like a synonym for "accurate", which is why it sounds odd in context: His accurate views blinded him.... Perhaps "his realism-based views"?

Comment: Putting in a context: He is a thinker in the field of international relations. What of the existing theories in the field he support? --He is definitely a realist ... And his realistic view keeps him from seeing the significance of human rights considerations.

Comment: Good -- then it sounds like a perfectly clear and correct usage in the context of a larger piece of writing with an explanatory frame. It is only misleading sans context. Like if I said "His statistic views made him oppose federal income tax." Because, you know, he was a famous state-rights advocate, known for statism. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about *obscure* (as suggested by 1006a) or *mask*?

M-W:

> [*obscure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure): to make dark, dim, or indistinct; to conceal or hide
> by or as if by covering
>
> [*mask*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mask): to cover up

Your example:

> His realistic view *obscures* the significance of human right
> considerations.
>
> His realistic view *masks* the significance of human right
> considerations.